# boost linking with visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, boost

I have successfully built boost using bjam and visual studio 2010 using this command:

bjam --build-dir=c:\boost --build-type=complete --toolset=msvc-10.0 address-model=64 architecture=x86 --with-system

I have also set the stage/lib directory as the lib directory in visual studio.

However, the linker gives me this:

fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_filesystem-vc90-mt-gd-1_50.lib'

Why is it looking for 'vc90' versions of the libraries? the vc100 version is there in the directory.. how do I change that?

Thanks.

Comment: Answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19817163/how-do-i-specify-which-version-of-boost-library-to-link-to?rq=1

Very annoying feature...

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly specify the paths to the libraries in project settings. First you need to include the library names that you want to link against in your project.

[image: Adding libs]

Now we have to specify the directories, where the libraries specified above can be found.

[image: Specifying directories where the libraries from the previous image are]

I hope, that helps.

Comment: Yes, I know about those... I set the directory just fine... my question was why is the autoload in boost looking for a v90 and not a v100, if I'm compiling it in vs2010... I got it to work simply renaming the compiled lib files to v90, but I'd still like to understand why it looked for the wrong file names...

Answer (score 0):

Check the compiler setting (You have choices for vc90 (2008), vc100 (2010)) in your project's properties.