# How do I specify, which version of boost library to link to?

Tags: c++, boost, linker-errors, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to migrate a project written in VS2012 to VS2013.

I successfully compiled boost 1.53.0 (I first tried 1.54.0, but got some compiler errors) and got libraries like
`libboost_filesystem-vc120-mt-1_53.lib`.

But when trying to build my project, the linker complains:

```
error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_filesystem-vc110-mt-1_53.lib'
```

I've been looking for some project settings in my entire solution to find out, why it's trying to load the older library version, but I didn't find anything.

How does the linker know, which library to use?
And how can I fix my problem?

Comment: "the linker complains" -- we'll need to see some error mesasges, likely.

Comment: This is exactly my question. Why is it looking for vc110 version and not vc120?

Comment: Aha, I see now.  Yes, see @MartinBeckett's answer.

Comment: @JohnDibling: No, I already built the vc120 version. But the linker is looking for an older version and I don't know why. I never specified which library to use. It just worked until now and I have no clue how the linker could know before, which library to use.

Comment: Probably a `#pragma comment (lib)`

Comment: In the boost code? Did they forget to update that for the vc120 version?

Comment: No, I've used Boost with VC120.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40648/discussion-between-ben-and-john-dibling)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the answer to my question and the solution to my problem in TheArtTrooper's answer to this thread:

[How do I build boost with new Visual Studio 2013 preview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17440810/how-do-i-build-boost-with-new-visual-studio-2013-preview)

The linker does know which library to use, because it is specified in **boost/config/auto_link.hpp**.

This file is missing a few lines of code to handle the vc120 version:

```
#  elif defined(BOOST_MSVC) && (BOOST_MSVC < 1800)

     // vc11:
#    define BOOST_LIB_TOOLSET "vc110"

#  elif defined(BOOST_MSVC)

     // vc12:
#    define BOOST_LIB_TOOLSET "vc120"
```

Now it compiles and links just fine!

Comment: Good spot, report it to the boost bug list