# Visual Studio 2013 (vs120) asks for wrong boost libraries

Tags: c++, boost, linker-errors, visual-studio-2013, file-not-found

I'm trying to compile one of my projects on Windows 7, using Visual Studio 2013. I've installed Boost 1.53 and setup the solution using cmake.

What happens is that now the compiled libraries of boost are in the form `libboost_*-vc120-mt(-gd)-1_53.lib`. In the linker project options, under the input tab, I have verified that the libraries that I need are there, and in fact the compiler is able to correctly read them.

However, for some reason that I absolutely can't understand, the linker is also trying to find libraries compiled as `vc110`. For example:

```
error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_filesystem-vc110-mt-gd-1_53.lib'
```

The Platform Toolset that is listed in the project option is "Visual Studio 2013 (v120)". I couldn't find any reference to vc110 in any of the project options. Can you help me understand what is happening?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This post thankfully solves my question. I wasn't able to find it before. The solution is to edit the `boost/config/auto_link.hpp` because the code inside is not able to handle `vc120`, and ends up suggesting `vc110`

[How do I specify, which version of boost library to link to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19817163/how-do-i-specify-which-version-of-boost-library-to-link-to?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

The library name is autogenerated in the boost header version.hpp

Possibly the version wasn't rebuilt, or you are pointing at the wrong header version?

Comment: To be completely honest, after building the library all names contained only the string `vc` for some reason, but cmake could not recognize them so I batch renamed them all. But does it really matter?

Comment: Please note that cmake was in fact looking for `vc120`.lib libraries, due to the compiler version I guess. And I only have this version of Boost on the machine.

Comment: I think that as long as the libs match the version in the auto_link it's ok.  I don't know if there is a linker format between vs2012/13 - probably not

Answer (score 0):

Instead of patching the config file try just defining a macro before the header inclusion .. this is what I did in my project

//#define BOOST_LIB_TOOLSET "vc100"
//#include