# Unresolved external objects with boost regex library

Tags: c++, boost

I've just started to learn C++ and now I have tried to use Boost Libraries. By the way, I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Professional.

I have downloaded the file **boost_1_55_0-bin-msvc-all-32-64.7z** and followed the instruction from this [tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#link-your-program-to-a-boost-library). But when I try to compile I get the errors:

```
1>libboost_regex-vc120-mt-gd-1_55.liberror LNK2019: external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::exception::exception(char const * const &)" (__imp_??0exception@std@@QAE@ABQBD@Z) sin resolver al que se hace referencia en la función "public: __thiscall std::logic_error::logic_error(char const *)" (??0logic_error@std@@QAE@PBD@Z)
1>libboost_regex-vc120-mt-gd-1_55.lib(regex.obj) : error LNK2001: external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::exception::exception(char const * const &)" (__imp_??0exception@std@@QAE@ABQBD@Z) sin resolver
1>libboost_regex-vc120-mt-gd-1_55.lib(w32_regex_traits.obj) : error LNK2001: external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::exception::exception(char const * const &)" (__imp_??0exception@std@@QAE@ABQBD@Z) sin resolver
1>libboost_regex-vc120-mt-gd-1_55.lib(instances.obj) : error LNK2019: external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: struct std::_Iterator_base12 * * __thiscall std::_Container_base12::_Getpfirst(void)const " (__imp_?_Getpfirst@_Container_base12@std@@QBEPAPAU_Iterator_base12@2@XZ) sin resolver al que se hace referencia en la función "protected: void __thiscall std::_Tree<class std::_Tmap_traits<int,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,struct std::less<int>,class std::allocator<struct std::pair<int const ,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > > >,0> >::_Orphan_ptr(class std::_Tree<class std::_Tmap_traits<int,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,struct std::less<int>,class std::allocator<struct std::pair<int const ,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > > >,0> > &,struct std::_Tree_node<struct std::pair<int const ,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >,void *> *)const " (?_Orphan_ptr@?$_Tree@V?$_Tmap_traits@HV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@U?$less@H@2@V?$allocator@U?$pair@$$CBHV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@std@@@2@$0A@@std@@@std@@IBEXAAV12@PAU?$_Tree_node@U?$pair@$$CBHV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@std@@PAX@2@@Z)
1>libboost_regex-vc120-mt-gd-1_55.lib(instances.obj) : error LNK2019: external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall std::_Container_base12::_Swap_all(struct std::_Container_base12 &)" (__imp_?_Swap_all@_Container_base12@std@@QAEXAAU12@@Z) sin resolver al que se hace referencia en la función "public: void __thiscall std::vector<struct boost::sub_match<char const *>,class std::allocator<struct boost::sub_match<char const *> > >::swap(class std::vector<struct boost::sub_match<char const *>,class std::allocator<struct boost::sub_match<char const *> > > &)" (?swap@?$vector@U?$sub_match@PBD@boost@@V?$allocator@U?$sub_match@PBD@boost@@@std@@@std@@QAEXAAV12@@Z)
1>libboost_regex-vc120-mt-gd-1_55.lib(regex_raw_buffer.obj) : error LNK2001: external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) char const * __cdecl std::_Winerror_map(int)" (__imp_?_Winerror_map@std@@YAPBDH@Z) sin resolver
1>libboost_regex-vc120-mt-gd-1_55.lib(instances.obj) : error LNK2001: external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) char const * __cdecl std::_Winerror_map(int)" (__imp_?_Winerror_map@std@@YAPBDH@Z) sin resolver
1>libboost_regex-vc120-mt-gd-1_55.lib(regex.obj) : error LNK2001: external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) char const * __cdecl std::_Winerror_map(int)" (__imp_?_Winerror_map@std@@YAPBDH@Z) sin resolver
1>libboost_regex-vc120-mt-gd-1_55.lib(regex_traits_defaults.obj) : error LNK2001: external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) char const * __cdecl std::_Winerror_map(int)" (__imp_?_Winerror_map@std@@YAPBDH@Z) sin resolver
1>libboost_regex-vc120-mt-gd-1_55.lib(w32_regex_traits.obj) : error LNK2001: external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) char const * __cdecl std::_Winerror_map(int)" (__imp_?_Winerror_map@std@@YAPBDH@Z) sin resolver
1>libboost_regex-vc120-mt-gd-1_55.lib(w32_regex_traits.obj) : error LNK2019: external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: bool __thiscall type_info::operator==(class type_info const &)const " (__imp_??8type_info@@QBE_NABV0@@Z) sin resolver al que se hace referencia en la función "public: virtual void * __thiscall boost::detail::sp_counted_impl_pd<struct HINSTANCE__ *,void (__cdecl*)(void *)>::get_deleter(class type_info const &)" (?get_deleter@?$sp_counted_impl_pd@PAUHINSTANCE__@@P6AXPAX@Z@detail@boost@@UAEPAXABVtype_info@@@Z)
1>D:\Fuentes\CPP\ConsoleReadDir\Debug\ConsoleReadDir.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 5 unresolved external
```

I have updated *Additional Library Directories* with the path: `D:\Descargas\boost_1_55_0-bin-msvc-all-32-64\boost_1_55_0\lib32-msvc-12.0`.

What I have to do to add the external objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your building a version of boost that predates Visual Studio 2015, see [How do I specify, which version of boost library to link to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19817163/how-do-i-specify-which-version-of-boost-library-to-link-to?rq=1)

The current version of [boost](http://www.boost.org/), `1.62` works fine. If you can't find a pre-built binary then it's easy enough to build the Windows libraries with MSVC, see: [boost installation in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35217511/boost-1-60-0-zip-installation-in-windows/35223257#35223257)